# Edición de una pregunta en inglés (traducirla)

Tags: discusión, traducciones

Me estaba preguntando que hacer en el siguiente caso: Sí una pregunta está en inglés y la puedo traducir (para que no sea cerrada), ¿Debo hacerlo?; Esta duda me surgió, pues hoy estaba viendo una revisión de edición y noté que el usuario que hizo la edición la tradujo. Que se debería hacer en este caso, ¿Aceptar la edición o rechazarla y proponer el cierre de la pregunta por idioma?

Comment: Usualmente se rechazan las ediciones porque, como usuarios, no podemos saber si el usuario es hispano hablante o no. Es mejor que sea el(la) autor(a) quien actualice la publicación.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Me parece que tu comentario debería publicarse como respuesta, ¿será que estás considerando hacerlo luego, cuando  tengas mas tiempo?

Comment: no se si es un duplicado pero aqui ya se trato el tema: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123/qu%C3%A9-hacer-con-esta-pregunta-en-ingl%C3%A9s-que-fue-traducida-a-espa%C3%B1ol-por-alguien

Comment: Yo pienso que se le podria decir en un comentario, algo como: Hola ... este sitio es para preguntas/respuesta en español, puede editar su pregunta a a dicho idioma o publicarla en ingles en stackoverflow.com. Si usted habla ingles podria decirle algo similar en ingles. Saludos